# DirectX 12 Resource binding

Tags: c++, resources, directx-12

How can I bind resources to different shader stages in D3D12?

I wrote two shaders, one vertexshader and one pixelshader:

Here is the Vertex shader:

```
//VertexShader.vs

float4 main(float3 posL : POSITION, uniform float4x4 gWVP) : SV_POSITION
{
    return mul(float4(posL, 1.0f), gWVP);
}
```

Here is the Pixelshader:

```
//PixelShader.ps

float4 main(float4 PosH : SV_POSITION, uniform float4 Color) : SV_Target
{
    return Color;
}
```

If I compile those two shaders with the `D3DCompile` function and reflect it with the `D3DReflect` and examine the BoundResorces member in the shader description they both have a constant buffer called $Params with contains the uniform variable respectively. The Problem is that both of those buffers are bound to slot 0. When binding resources I have to use the ID3D12RootSignature interface, which can bind resources to the resource slots. How can I bind the $Params buffer of the vertex shader only to the vertex shader and the $Params buffer of the Pixel shader only to the pixel shader?

Thanks in advance,

Philinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DX12, the performant solution here is to create a root signature that meets your application needs, and ideally [declare it in your HLSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn913202.aspx) as well. You don't want to change root signatures often, so you definitely want to make one that works for a large swath of your shaders.

> Remember DX12 is Direct3D without training wheels, magic, or shader patching so you just have to do it all explicitly yourself. Ease-of-use is a non-goal for Direct3D 12. There are plenty of good reason to stick with Direct3D 11 unless your application and developer resources merit the extra control Direct3D 12 affords you. *With great power comes great responsibility*.

I believe you can achieve what you want with something like:

```
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE descRange[1];
descRange[0].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 0);
CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER rootParameters[2];
rootParameters[0].InitAsDescriptorTable(
    1, &descRange[0], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX); // b0
rootParameters[1].InitAsDescriptorTable(
    1, &descRange[0], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL); // b0

// Create the root signature.
CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureDesc(_countof(rootParameters),
     rootParameters, 0, nullptr,
     D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);

ComPtr<ID3DBlob> signature;
ComPtr<ID3DBlob> error;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rootSignatureDesc,
     D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &signature, &error));
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    device->CreateRootSignature(0, signature->GetBufferPointer(),
        signature->GetBufferSize(),
        IID_PPV_ARGS(m_rootSignature.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())));
```